# update column in one table based on condition in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgresql. Both tables have the remarks column. When I run this i get an error stating column inv not found.

```
UPDATE inventory SET INV.REMARKS = INV.REMARKS || ', $A'
FROM  priceguide_inventory pg, inventory INV
WHERE (INV.Lot_ID = pg.Lot_ID)
AND INV.Condition = 'New'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE a SET Remarks=b.Remarks || ',$A' FROM inventory a JOIN priceguide_inventory b ON a.Lot_ID = b.Lot_ID WHERE a.condition='New'
```

Comment: I had to make a small change, move the inventory over to the top

Comment: UPDATE inventory inv SET REMARKS = pg.REMARKS || ', $A'
FROM priceguide_inventory pg on inv.lot_id = pg.lot_id
where soldtotalqty > (forsaletotalqty+(forsaletotalqty*.3)) as pg
AND Condition = 'New'

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is off, try this instead:

```
UPDATE inventory AS inv
SET REMARKS = REMARKS || ', $A'
FROM priceguide_inventory AS pg
WHERE inv.Lot_ID = pg.Lot_ID AND
      inv.Condition = 'New'
```

Check the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) for the update join synatax.

Comment: Now i get Error executing SQL statement. ERROR: column "inv" of relation "inventory" does not exist
  Position: 29

Comment: Post your full schema, my first query should have been working.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE inventory 
SET REMARKS = REMARKS || ', $A'
FROM  priceguide_inventory pg
WHERE inventory.Lot_ID = priceguide_inventory.Lot_ID AND 
      inventory.Condition = 'New'
```